# Integration Jira Software with zabbix

Tags: jira, zabbix

How can I create automatically tickets in JS from zabbix’s triggers?

I tried this via the built-in Jira webhook, Jira service desk, but nothing worked.Is it even possible to do this via webhook?
Zabbix 5.0.6.